# Easier way to call an absurd number of functions

Tags: c

So I'm calling a whole lot of functions what kind of have a similar pattern 
(disclaimer:I did not write these)
They go like so:

```
 Write_thing0<x>_object00<y>(somedata);
```

where `<x>` takes values from 0 to 6 and `<y>` takes values from 1 to 20.

Is there a sane way to do this, perhaps in a loop? The token-pasting operator was suggested but that doesn't work or I can't find a way to use it.

Edit:
Okay so I'll go into more depth:

```
Write_thing000_object001_A(uint8);
Write_thing000_object001_B(uint8);
Write_thing000_object001_C(uint16);
.................................
Write_thing000_object001_Z(uint8);

Write_thing000_object002_A(uint8);
.................................
Write_thing000_object002_Z(uint8);
/* all the way up to object 20, then thing changes to 001 and object count resets */
```

the pattern of parameters stays the same in each A-Z block.
I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Try making an array of function pointers with each pointer pointing to one of the "absurd number" of functions. After that iterate through the array calling each function.

Comment: @JimRogers -- why is that better?

Comment: It is always helpful for us to see the actual code -- if you can't post it here because it is large you could post it on gist.github.com or some other posting site.

Comment: When you talk about token-pasting operator, did you use the X-Macro technique?

Comment: @Hogan -- C is not an interpreted language. The names of functions are converted to function addresses by the compiler. One cannot therefore call a function name derived at runtime. Normal compilation strips the symbolic information (names) from the executable.

Comment: Please show a small example of what the functions look like and how you want to call them

Comment: I know that @JimRogers I was writing C code over 30 years ago -- If the design is to call 120 functions I don't see why putting them in pointers serves any purpose.

Comment: @JimRogers I was trying to lighten it up, there's actually way more, about 1000 total.

Comment: Sounds like a bad design

Comment: @Simone-Cu I will look into it, I'm not familiar with that. Thanks.

Comment: @AbjectFailure -- We need to understand why you are calling so many functions -- then we can tell you how to improve.  Right now all we know is you are calling a lot of functions.   It may be that you need to do so.  It may be that you don't and there is a way to use a trick (loop or pointers or something else) to make your code better.  Right now there is no way to know what your code does and how to improve it.  Please post more details.

Comment: Do the functions all have the same signature?

Comment: @wildplasser they sadly do not, different types of parameters. I can't show a clear example because this is from work but I think I've described the only pattern I can recognise.

Comment: @AbjectFailure If you cannot show a clear example, then it's nearly impossible to help

Comment: You always can come up with something demonstrating the real problem. If you can't, we probably won't be able to help you.

Comment: OK, a simple question - where these functions are coming from? Who have defined them? Some automatic tool? Do you have a control of this tool?

Comment: I've perhaps chosen my words poorly. I'll write an example as best I can and paste it here.

Comment: Sounds like a plan

Comment: @AbjectFailure-- ok I wrote a clear example in my answer -- tell me how that code differs from what you have and how my solution won't work.

Comment: @EugeneSh. They used a generator. I do not have access to it.

Comment: Maybe it still can be adjusted to generate better suited code. Or to generate calling code as well.

Comment: @AbjectFailure -- then you shouldn't work on this project if you don't have access to the original source.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers, it's an overwhelming about in a short time. I'll investigate and get back to everyone as fast as I humanly can.

Comment: Just write your program which generates the C code containing your many calls. You might use [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [Python](http://python.org/) or something else (perhaps even C) to write such a meta-program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with x-macros:

```
#define CALL_ONE(i,j) call_func_##i##_##j(); // Put your function name here.
#define LIST_A(m,d) m(0,d) m(1,d) m(2,d) // Replace 0,1,2 with actual values.
#define LIST_B(m,d) m(X,d) m(Y,d) m(Z,d) // Replace X,Y,Z with actual values.

#define CALL_A(x,unused) LIST_A(CALL_ONE,x)
#define CALL_B() LIST_B(CALL_A,)
```

Now, `CALL_B()` expands to:

```
call_func_0_X(); call_func_1_X(); call_func_2_X();
call_func_0_Y(); call_func_1_Y(); call_func_2_Y();
call_func_0_Z(); call_func_1_Z(); call_func_2_Z();
```

It should be easy to adapt this for your purposes.

Comment: Why is this an improvement to the code?  Sure it has less lines of code but it compiles to the same thing -- all it does is hide what is probably a fundamental design flaw in the base system.

Comment: @Hogan Exactly because it requires less code, `O(n+m)` instead of `O(n*m)` (before preprocessing, that is). I agree that something's not right with the design here, but I'm simply giving OP what they asked for, a way to not type 600 function calls by hand.

Comment: This has helped tremendously, though I'll have to spend more time trying to understand x-macros. Thank you.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat -- I said "it has less lines of code" but "compiles to the same thing".  It is not less code when it runs.  It does not change performance.   It is not an improvement in the functionality of the system.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat -- The reason I'm pointing this out is because it is important that the OP understands what is actually being done here -- if they had a concern about performance or someone else expressed a concern about the design -- this trick is not changing anything EXCEPT what how the .c source file looks.  Any expectation this change will make any difference in performance or design should be squashed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat -- In addition, the problems with this code stem from it being generated code.  If you are going to maintain the code you need to use the tool that generated the code.  Changing the code to use macros as a way to maintain it is a bad choice.  You should use the generator or re-write the code.  Generated code is not maintainable without the original tool in almost every case.

Comment: I agree, this is only about not having a file with 3000 lines. It was bad design to start with. I'm still trying to completely understand X-macros and would love a good resource for this. Like for example if I want to expand CALL_ONE(a,b,c,d) call_func_ ##a##_ ##b##_ ##c(d); < - where b and d are x-macros. I've been trying to wrap my head around how they work but I have a mental block.

Comment: @AbjectFailure Off the top of my head, I'm not sure how to easily expand this to `n` variables.

Answer (score 0):

From your example you seem to suggest that the code looks like this:

```
 Write_thing000_object001(somedata);
 Write_thing000_object002(somedata);
 Write_thing000_object003(somedata);
 Write_thing000_object004(somedata);
 Write_thing000_object005(somedata);
  /// lots of lines
 Write_thing006_object0020(somedata);
```

If this is exactly what your code looks like fine.  But it raises a lot of questions to me

1) Does some data stay the same for each function call (or set of calls)

2) Is every function name used or is a subset of names

3) What do all these functions do?  It seems likely give the name that they could be all be rewritten like this:

```
        Write_thing_object(somedata,x,y);
```

then you just have one function and you can put the whole thing in a loop -- why can't you do that?

> Also as a side note, this is often called a 'dispatch pattern', if you simple make this function and have it call the correct other function.  You could do this efficiently by creating a 2 dimension array of function pointers.  If this is what you need to do I could show you how to do that.